# how to find if prefix is a match to some string in a set in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, collections, prefix

I am trying to go through a predefined dir path set but I only have the prefix of the path

I have tried use include? or find a method that does that.
I can only think about the trivial solution of define a regexp and go for each in the set, but that seems to be not so ruby-like style

```
require 'set'

legal_paths = Set['A/B/C', 'A/D/E', 'A/F/G']
Dir.glob('**/system.log').each do |fd|
    if failed_tests_path.include?(fd) #fd for example = A/F/G/E/system.log, A/B/C/K/system.log etc...
        puts fd
    end
end
```

I want fd to be only system.log files that the paths are including inside the set (the set holds the prefix to the path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are only the prefix, try `String#start_with?`:

```
require 'set'

legal_paths = Set['A/B/C', 'A/D/E', 'A/F/G']
files = Dir.glob('**/system.log').select do |fd|
  fd.start_with?(*legal_paths)
end
```

Why not make use of the fact that you can specify these prefixes in the glob?

```
legal_paths = ['A/B/C', 'A/D/E', 'A/F/G']
files = Dir.glob("{#{legal_paths.join(',')}}/**/system.log")
```

Note though that if the `legal_paths` are input by the user, the above might not be secure as the user could traverse to parent directories using `..`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. my path list is not from input by the user, but I was hoping to get the efficiency of the set, the same as I would've got if I used the full path. joining the set to one big string won't help me because the original code holds a very big set

Comment: What about the first solution?

Comment: `start_with` takes multiple arguments: `fd.start_with ('A/B/C', 'A/D/E', 'A/F/G')`